# Why do set operations work with iterables only when using methods?

Tags: python, set

Why do [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set) operations work with arbitrary iterables when using set methods, but not operators? To show what I mean:

```
>>> {0, 1, 2, 3}.intersection([0, 1])
{0, 1}
>>> {0, 1, 2, 3} & [0, 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list'
>>>
>>> {0, 1, 2, 3}.union([4, 5])
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> {0, 1, 2, 3} | [4, 5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'set' and 'list'
```

Comment: Are you asking why the Python developers designed `set` that way or do you just want a link to where this behavior appears in the documentation?  (It's here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.copy)

Comment: It looks like I never reached that part of the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> Note, the non-operator versions of `union()`, `intersection()`, `difference()`, and `symmetric_difference()`, `issubset()`, and `issuperset()` methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. **This precludes error-prone constructions like `set('abc') & 'cbs'` in favor of the more readable `set('abc').intersection('cbs')`.**

It was considered less error-prone this way.